# how to plot multi indexed dataframe in python using python?

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, plot, ipython, dataframe

I have multi-indexed  dataframe with single column. I want to plot stacked bar graph based on that dataframe. The data is as follows:

```
df= pd.DataFrame(index=pd.MultiIndex([[1,2,3],['open','closed']],[[0,0,1,1,2,2],[0,1,0,1,0,1]]))

df['id']=[23,6,12,4,31,16]
df
        id
state
1 closed 23
  open    6
2 closed 12
  open    4
3 closed 31
  open   16
```

Comment: Here State is index and id is column. State consist of 'closed' and 'open'. First level indices are 1,2,3...and second level indices are 'closed', 'open'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to `unstack` your dataframe:

```
%matplotlib inline
df.unstack().plot(kind='bar', stacked=True)
```

[image]